# Custom editor template of KendoUI ForeignKey Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using KendoUI ASP Wrapper, i need help changing the default ForeignKey editor for "ActivityCodeID" to AutoComplete. How do i change it?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TimeEntry>()
    .Name("grid-timeentry-project")
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(record => record.TimeEntryID);
                        model.Field(f => f.TimeSheetID).DefaultValue(0);
                        model.Field(f => f.TimeEntryTypeID).DefaultValue(ViewBag.ProjectTimeEntryTypeId);
                        model.Field(f => f.ActivityCodeID);
                        model.Field(f => f.Description);
                        model.Field(f => f.Duration);
                        model.Field(f => f.DateAdded);                     
                    })
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetProjectTimeEntries", "TimeEntry"))
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
                 {
                     columns.Bound(r => r.TimeEntryID).Hidden(true);
                     columns.Bound(r => r.TimeSheetID).Hidden(true);
                     columns.Bound(r => r.TimeEntryTypeID).Hidden(true);
                     columns.ForeignKey(r => r.ActivityCodeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["AllActivityCodes"], "ActivityCodeID", "ActivityCode1").Title("ActivityCode");                                         
                     columns.Bound(r => r.Description);
                     columns.Bound(r => r.Duration).Title("Duration (s)");
                     columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(170);
                 })
      )
```

I tried to modified the DataAnnotation of my EF model and declared the EditorTemplate but it's still using the default "GridForeignKey" editortemplate.

Here's my EF.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TimeEntryMetaData))]
public partial class TimeEntry
{
}

public class TimeEntryMetaData
{
    [UIHint("ActivityCodeIDEditor")]
    public int ActivityCodeID { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my "ActivityCodeIDEditor" editor template. I can't get the "asdf" and hence assume the editor template is not considered.

```
    @model object
<span>asdf</span>
@*@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
```

Please help. thanks!
      )*@

Comment: https://kendoeditortemplate.codeplex.com/

Comment: I was having the same problem, your question tipped me off to move my custom editortemplate is into the `Shared > EditorTemplates` folder. working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is special column method which lets you specify the name of the editor template. Try

```
columns.bound(x=>x.some).EditorTemplateName("foo");
```

Comment: Ya, i'm aware of that but I can't set the "EditorTemplateName" for columns.ForeignKey(). I think it's only available for columns.boud()